# Undefined variable: vaccine_feed (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\webapp\resources\views\addstock.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting an undefined variable when trying to pass data from my controller to a view from a database.

```
Part of my Controller:
public function index()
    {
      $vaccine_feed = Vaccines::All();
        return view('welcome', [
          'vaccines' => $vaccines,
          'user' => $user,
          'vaccine_feed' => $vaccine_feed
        ]);
    }




View:

foreach($vaccine_feed as $vaccines ) {

}
```

I've added my routes below, if that helps at all

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('/logout', function () {
    Auth::logout();
    Session::flush();
    return view('welcome');
});


Route::get('/addstock', 'AddForm@getStockForm');
Route::post('/addstock', 'AddForm@postStockForm');
```

Comment: I added my routes if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Are you including addstock.blade.php in your welcome template. Because that view has different scope you may want to pass your $vaccine_feed to wherever you are including.

Comment: My addstock is on a different route than the welcome blade, i tried adding it to the welcome blade but i get the same error

Answer (score -1):

Try dd($vaccine_feed) in your controller (before the return) and see if it returning anything.

Comment: It's still giving me the same thing, undefined variable, it doesnt look like it triggers